# Cannot set Context in open-xchange

Tags: mariadb, debian

Hello everybody when i run:

```
/opt/open-xchange/sbin/createcontext -A oxadminmaster -P pw_for_master -c 1 -u oxadmin -d "Context Admin" -g Admin -s User -p pw_for_admin -L defaultcontext -e oxadmin@myDomain -q 1024 --access-combination-name=all
```

following error occurs:

```
context 1 could not be created:
Server response:
 No suitable database available to complete the operation. Please ensure registered databases are reachable and their schemas have enough capacity left and are up-to-date.; exceptionId 321429037-66
        at com.openexchange.admin.storage.mysqlStorage.OXUtilMySQLStorage.getNextDBHandleByWeight(OXUtilMySQLStorage.java:4080)
        at com.openexchange.admin.plugin.hosting.storage.mysqlStorage.OXContextMySQLStorage.create(OXContextMySQLStorage.java:1648)
        at com.openexchange.admin.plugin.hosting.rmi.impl.OXContext.createmaincall(OXContext.java:1240)
        at com.openexchange.admin.rmi.impl.OXContextCommonImpl.createcommon(OXContextCommonImpl.java:178)
        at com.openexchange.admin.plugin.hosting.rmi.impl.OXContext.create(OXContext.java:462)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:303)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:279)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:164)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:235)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:180)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.create(Unknown Source)
        at com.openexchange.admin.console.context.Create.maincall(Create.java:150)
        at com.openexchange.admin.console.context.CreateCore.commonfunctions(CreateCore.java:149)
        at com.openexchange.admin.console.context.Create.execute(Create.java:94)
        at com.openexchange.admin.console.context.Create.main(Create.java:85)
```

I did run

```
/opt/open-xchange/sbin/initconfigdb --configdb-pass=db_password -a --mysql-root-passwd=root_password
```

```
/opt/open-xchange/sbin/oxinstaller --no-license --servername=oxserver  --configdb-user=openexchange  --configdb-writehost=localhost --network-listener-host=localhost --servermemory 2048 --master-pass=pw_for_master --configdb-pass=pw_for_db --network-listener-host=localhost  --ajp-bind-port=localhost
```

And could register:

- database (groupware database)
- server
- filestore;

but i am not quite sure, what i registered as database, because with show databases;
i do not find my specified database (name is oxdatabase) in the results.

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| configdb           |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

When i created oxdatabase manually and ran

```
/opt/open-xchange/sbin/createschemas -A oxadminmaster -P pw_for_master -n oxdatabase
```

but this resulted in:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'openexchange'@'localhost' (using password: YES); exceptionId 321429037-68
        at com.openexchange.admin.storage.mysqlStorage.OXUtilMySQLStorageCommon.getSimpleSQLConnectionFor(OXUtilMySQLStorageCommon.java:137)
        at com.openexchange.admin.storage.mysqlStorage.OXUtilMySQLStorageCommon.listDatabases(OXUtilMySQLStorageCommon.java:156)
        at com.openexchange.admin.storage.mysqlStorage.OXUtilMySQLStorage.createDatabaseSchemas(OXUtilMySQLStorage.java:1389)
        at com.openexchange.admin.rmi.impl.OXUtil.createSchemas(OXUtil.java:475)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor289.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:303)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:279)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:164)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:235)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:180)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.createSchemas(Unknown Source)
        at com.openexchange.admin.console.util.database.CreateSchemas$1.run(CreateSchemas.java:97)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I checked the settings: PW is ok; user is ok; grants should be ok (i granted star.star);
On disk about 90 GB left; only one partition.
OS: Debian 10
I run as root

So my questions are:

- Does my error occur because of my (missing) database?
- If yes could someone provide me with the schema for the groupware database?
- And why does the error in createschemas occur?

Comment: Thank you for your edit @Sven Eberth, but could i know the reason for removing my regards?

Comment: Stack Overflow is like an encyclopedia, posts should be free of meta information and focus on the content. See the answers in [this meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it.

First step - maybe optional

Re-install Buster

Secondly change hostname to server name -> e.g oxserver